# Twitter single url request

Tags: twitter

Is it possible to make a request to Twitter API in a single like? (http request?)

In example you can get the JSON in the Facebook API by the following single url:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Can something be possible similarly in twitter. E.g.:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?consumer_key=CONSUMER_KEY&consumer_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET&access_token=ACCESS_TOEKN&token_secret=TOKEN_SECRET
```

I find the twitter documentation quite stiff. If somebody has another proposal to get me understand how the communication with the API works I would be glad.

Comment: See my answer to your question [here][1].

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713394/access-additional-twitter-user-info/29782286#29782286