# Twitter oauth not working on Azure

Tags: azure, twitter, oauth

I have built a mobile app with an Azure backend, and I am authorizing users with Google, Facebook, Microsoft and Twitter. All of these work fine except Twitter.

My authorization (in the backend) is done like this:

```
 [Authorize]
public class AuthenticationController : ApiController 
{

    [HttpGet, Route("api/getUserIdentity")]
    public async Task<string> GetUserIdentity()
    {

        string requestUrl = "";
        string userID = "";

        try
        {
            FacebookCredentials credentials = await User.GetAppServiceIdentityAsync<FacebookCredentials>(Request);
             requestUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token="
                + credentials.AccessToken;
            userID = credentials.UserId;
        }
        catch (Exception) { } //if it is not facebook, will throw an exception here
        if (requestUrl == "")
        {
            try
            {
                TwitterCredentials credentials = await User.GetAppServiceIdentityAsync<TwitterCredentials>(Request);
                requestUrl = " https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token="
                    + credentials.AccessToken;
                userID = credentials.UserId;
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
        }
        if (requestUrl == "")
        {
            try
            {
                GoogleCredentials credentials = await User.GetAppServiceIdentityAsync<GoogleCredentials>(Request);
                requestUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?access_token="
                    + credentials.AccessToken;
                userID = credentials.UserId;
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
        }

        if (requestUrl == "")
        {
            try
            {
                MicrosoftAccountCredentials credentials = await User.GetAppServiceIdentityAsync<MicrosoftAccountCredentials>(Request);
                requestUrl = "https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/?method=GET&access_token="
                    + credentials.AccessToken;
                userID = credentials.UserId;
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
        }
        if (requestUrl != "")
        {
            try
            {
                // Create an HttpClient request.
                var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();

                // Request the current user info from Google.
                var resp = await client.GetAsync(requestUrl);
```

The credentials object I get back is valid, with a UserID and AccessToken.

When I call GetAsync(...) using the Twitter request URL, I get a 404 (not found) exception. For good measure, I tried all the URLs twitter give you but with the same result. But all the other auth providers work fine.

I have put the twitter API key and secret into the Azure portal correctly (no spaces anywhere), and have set the Twitter app access level to Read, Write and Direct Messages.
The twitter account username and password are valid, because I can go straight to the Twitter account from the initial sign-in screen.

Since this works with all the other authentication providers, I must be missing something here. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After more detailed research, it seems getting user data from Twitter is a more complicated affair than from the other authentication providers.

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713394/access-additional-twitter-user-info) explains how to do it